# How to sortByChild("Timestamp") on a hashmapped recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

So I am following [this firebase + kotlin chatting app guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaeTFNqKA2M&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JE-jiBHjxlmXEkQkum_M3R-&index=10). All is fine but the message list is not sorted by timestamp,

I have read through other sources and it says the only way is by using sortByChild("timestamp") but it still will not sort.

Below is the code:

```js
// creating hashmap for each message
val latestMessagesMap = HashMap<String, ChatMessage>()

    //creating adapter
    private fun refreshRecyclerViewMessages() {
        adapter.clear()
        latestMessagesMap.values.forEach {
            adapter.add(DaftarPesan(it))
        }
    }

    //start creating recycler view
    private fun listenForLatestMessages() {
        val fromId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid

        // get Firebase database path
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/pesan-terakhir-pengguna/$fromId")

        // sort by timestamp for each message
        ref.orderByChild("timestamp").addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener {
            override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    val chatMessage = snapshot.getValue(ChatMessage::class.java) ?: return
                    latestMessagesMap[snapshot.key!!] = chatMessage

                    //use the adapter
                    refreshRecyclerViewMessages()
                } else {
                }
            }
            override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                val chatMessage = snapshot.getValue(ChatMessage::class.java) ?: return
                latestMessagesMap[snapshot.key!!] = chatMessage
                refreshRecyclerViewMessages()
            }

            override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            }
            override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
    }

    val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
```

And here is the ViewHolder class:

```js
//starting with viewolder class
class DaftarPesan(val chatMessage: ChatMessage): Item<GroupieViewHolder>( ) {
    var chatPartnerUser: DataProfilUsaha? = null

    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val chatPartnerId: String


        // getting the sender uid
        if (chatMessage.fromId == FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid) {
            chatPartnerId = chatMessage.toId
        } else {
            chatPartnerId = chatMessage.fromId
        }

        // getting the sender's profile picture and name
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/profile/$chatPartnerId")
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    chatPartnerUser = snapshot.getValue(ProfileData::class.java)
                    
// putting sender name to text view
viewHolder.itemView.daftar_nama_pengirim_pesan_pedagang.text =
                        chatPartnerUser?.namaUsaha


                    val targetImageView = viewHolder.itemView.picture_daftar_pesan_pedagang
                    Picasso.get().load(chatPartnerUser?.coverImageUrl).into(targetImageView)
                } else {

                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })


    }
```

And here is the database structure:

```js
"pesan-terakhir-pengguna": {
    "76UJp5x9WcdH94os8s9q952uI2": {
      "B4ftYzLXLcOsDiChjMAXOgnBnar1": {
        "fromId": "P6scAzLXLcOsDiChjMAXOgnBnar1",
        "id": "-NBXTFVboixKDNepRIhD",
        "text": "test",
        "timestamp": 1662730703,
        "toId": "76UJp5x9WcdH94os8s9q952uI2"
      }
    }
```

Here is the rules on firebase:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": auth != null,
    ".write": auth != null,
      "pesan-terakhir-pengguna": {
        "$uid": {
          ".indexOn": "timestamp"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Here is the log cat when the message recycler view is created.

```js
2022-09-11 20:46:46.974 18714-18714/com.example.gesit I/MSHandlerLifeCycle: isMultiSplitHandlerRequested: windowingMode=1 isFullscreen=true isPopOver=false isHidden=false skipActivityType=false isHandlerType=true this: DecorView@bfc1c4[MainScreen]
2022-09-11 20:46:46.992 18714-18714/com.example.gesit I/MSHandlerLifeCycle: isMultiSplitHandlerRequested: windowingMode=1 isFullscreen=true isPopOver=false isHidden=false skipActivityType=false isHandlerType=true this: DecorView@bfc1c4[MainScreen]
2022-09-11 20:46:47.020 18714-18714/com.example.gesit I/ViewRootImpl@fdb127d[MainScreen]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
2022-09-11 20:46:47.020 18714-18714/com.example.gesit I/MSHandlerLifeCycle: isMultiSplitHandlerRequested: windowingMode=1 isFullscreen=true isPopOver=false isHidden=false skipActivityType=false isHandlerType=true this: DecorView@bfc1c4[MainScreen]
```

Comment: At first glance that code in the first snippet looks correct and should return the messages for the user order by their timestamp. Can you add some logging to the code that show the offending values, and then edit your question to include the updated code and its output?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the log cat when the recycler view is opened. And I have also provided the Database rule. Are those that are needed? Thank you.